# What should I follow, if two altimeters show different altitudes?

Tags: flight-instruments, altimeter

My school airplane has a Garmin G5 Electronic Flight Instrument and round gauge altimeter,
but they have almost 50ft differential. The G5 shows 50 feet higher on the same altimeter setting.

So in IFR, when I shoot the approach or cruise flight, my primary altimeter is the G5 so I follow my G5 altimeter.

But my instructor said "you hit the minimum, because standby (round gauge) showing below (-50ft) the minimum..."

In this case should I follow my round gauge altimeter? Even though the G5 is alive?

Comment: "my primary altimeter is the G5" Why?

Comment: As a non-aviator layperson, I would _always_ chose whichever shows the lowest altitude - I'd much rather find that there's 50ft of unexpected descent left before touchdown, than the opposite!

Comment: @Noughtnaut Satellite (GPS) and barometric (normal) altimeters are never used to determine touchdown height, or used at all below the MDA or DH ("decision height"). In that regime only radio (radar) altimeters are useful, and still are not a primary landing aid except for autoland.

Comment: >The instructor said "you hit the minimum ..." Actually you did, on both altimeters. But, if you use your round gauge as your primary, make sure it is set to the local pressure where you are landing by checking the [Kollsman window](https://tghaviation.com/aircraft-instrument-services/getting-to-know-your-kollsman-window-and-barber-pole/), and adjusting it as needed.

Comment: Take the average between both ;)

Comment: The old "man with two watches never knows what time it is" conundrum.

Comment: @noughtnaut, as a non-aviator layperson, hopefully you (*and 15 others...*) learned something from Chris' answer!   I get your point though.  ;)

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Why such needless nitpicking from everyone? 윤상우 did mention the altimeter setting. In the same way others could be reminding you that one should not just set it to some local pressure but the QNH valid from the locally valid certified official station.

Answer (score 34):

The G5 is not certified as a primary altimeter- its information is advisory only. From a legal standpoint, your primary altimeter is always the certified one- in your case, the steam gauge one.

Answer (score 14):

Garmin itself [says](https://support.garmin.com/en-MY/?faq=tdu65LfVl08mM85HAPoPTA):

> With the Auto Calibration feature turned on, the altimeter accuracy can range from +/- 50 to 125 feet (same as GPS elevation).

You can draw your own conclusions from this!